# download content from url to txt

Tags: java, url, html, download

I am totally lost here. I tried to check any previous answers and just couldn't find a solution to my problem. 
Is there any code to download a webpage content to txt, by entering the url ?
Thnx

Comment: *"I tried to check any previous answers"*  List 3 you looked at.  Describe what about the answers did not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

From the oracle site:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you're not constrained with Java, you can use **wget www.myurl.com > text.txt**

Comment: @gerrytan *"'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*  I am constrained by not having `wget` installed.